# Drawing on separate thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a "public static" class called "DrawTest" and inside is a method

```
public static DrawRandomRectangle(Bitmap g)
{

}
```

I want to call that method and draw bunches of stuff and then update the pictureBox that uses the image on a separate thread.

---

To simplify, I'm not trying to make anything specific I'm just trying to learn how to draw and update an image inside of a picturebox on a separate thread.

Answer (score 6):

The term for what you want to do is called [Double Buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics). You will draw your image on a separate thread then once it is finished you move it on to the UI in one step.

The MSDN has a [entire subsection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229622) on using double buffering in managed classes.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, Does this allow me to draw an image one pixel at a time slowly  without the app freezing up.

Comment: Yes, read the How To: pages from the MSDN link in my answer on "Manually Manage a Buffered Graphics" and "Manually Render a Buffered Graphics"